# Can I, as an iOS developer, access a video signal provided to the device through an RCA to 30 pin connector?

Tags: ios, video

I'm looking to process a video feed using an external source, and wondering if the standard issue RCA to 30 pin connector cable would be the right solution.

Here is the standard Apple cable: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC748ZM/A/apple-composite-av-cable

I don't know much about iOS programming, but I've done some and can't find an answer to whether I can access the feed in reverse (normally the cable is used to stream video out so you can connect it to your TV/what-have-you).

Anyone know?  Thanks and a Merry Christmas to you!

Comment: You wanna you use your **own** data, from your **own** app, on your **own** device? [Then pay for it to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)!

Comment: @H2CO3: In traditional Apple fashion. You might be able to do it, if you pay us. And even if you do, we'll only consider it.

Comment: <3 Apple.  I'm guessing it's much easier (cheaper too) with Android?