# How to feed RCA video into Iphone/Ipad?

Tags: ios, video, video-capture

I am not an electrical engineer. How does one go about encoding rca video feed into an line-in / headphone jack so an app can decode and display the video? Is there another way tru the 30 pin or lighting connector?

[Other post here similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962658/can-i-as-an-ios-developer-access-a-video-signal-provided-to-the-device-through)

Answer (score 0):

So after long hours of investigation I think the best option is to get USB capture device and plug it in to a Source machine then just use http://skjm.com/icam/ to see the video.

One could use a live steaming Wifi devices like ones of these
[http://www.amazon.com/Hauppauge-Broadway-HD-Streaming-Computers-Smartphones/dp/B005LMWPNM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005LMWPNM)